# How can I multithread the creation of a lazily loaded property?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

```
 - (NSHashTable *)pollers
 {
    if (!_pollers) {
        dispatch_sync(self.serialQueue, ^{
            _pollers = [NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable];
        });
    }

    return _pollers;
 }
```

pollers is a nonatomic property on a singleton. There are some other methods in the singleton where objects are added to pollers, and I'm using @synchronized for their addition ([self.pollers addObject:____]).

Anyway... I have a question about the code above. If 2 threads simultaneously call this function, they could both get past the `if (!_pollers)` code, and then both will dispatch the `_pollers = [NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable];` code synchronously on our custom serialQueue. So we'll actually run the code twice.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: OP, you seem to have a habit of not accepting answers. **It's very helpful when you accept (click on the green tick on) the answer that *solved* your problem and was the *most* helpful**. It is important so that the community knows which solution worked for you, and helps offer a feeling of closure to the question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You only need a single `dispatch_once` function for this**

Your serial queue is now redundant, as `dispatch_once` will ensure that the block is only called once (even if invoked at the same time from multiple threads), [contrary to what pds says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35048275/2976878).

[The documentation clearly states that:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_once)

> If [dispatch_once is] called simultaneously from multiple threads, **this function waits synchronously until the block has completed.**

Your `if` statement is also redundant, [as pointed out by Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047856/how-can-i-multithread-the-creation-of-a-lazily-loaded-property#comment57822459_35048275).

**Therefore you just want:**

```
- (NSHashTable *)pollers
 {
    static dispatch_once_t t;
    dispatch_once(&t, ^{
        _pollers = [NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable];
    });

    return _pollers;
}
```

It's also worth noting that you'll need a thread safe implementation of your singleton's `sharedInstance` in order for this to be bulletproof. You can do this in much the same way with a `dispatch_once`. For example:

```
static singleton* sharedInstance;

+(instancetype) sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t t;
    dispatch_once(&t, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: Has the problem, that if 2 different objects of this class exist, only first will return nonnil result

Comment: @Alistra but this is a singleton... Provided OP has made the singleton init code thread-safe (through using this code for his shared instance), this will work fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dispatch_once` like this

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
  dispatch_sync(self.serialQueue, ^{
    _pollers = [NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable];
  });
});
return pollers;
```

Comment: you might as well put the `dispatch_once` outside the if statement, as it only needs to be evaluated once and the `dispatch_sync` onto the serial queue is also now redundant as it can only be called once.

Comment: not a good solution, as this code will run once for all the objects

Comment: not true. From the documentation on `dispatch_once` "*If called simultaneously from multiple threads, this function waits synchronously until the block has completed.*"

Comment: You don't need to guard the `dispatch_once()` invocation with the `if`. It's redundant. If the Block has run, the variable is set.

Comment: @JoshCaswell completely overlooked that! both the if statement and serial queue are redundant.

Comment: Removed the if guard from the answer. Pretty sure you can not remove dispatch_sync to the self.serialQueue since this is where the block will be submitted.